# Attach an event receiver to profile property update

Tags: user-profile, event-handlers, event-receivers, user-profile-property, events

Do someone know if it's possible to attach an event receiver to profile updates?

The goal would be to update an external system (such as a CRM) when a user is updating his profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As James said, you could create a timer job to sync profile changes with the external system. But, to detect the changes in user profile properties, I would suggest you to look into `UserProfileChangeCollection` because it contains a complete log of changed user profiles.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://server1"))
           {
               SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site.WebApplication.ServiceApplicationProxyGroup, SPSiteSubscriptionIdentifier.Default);
               UserProfileManager profileConfigManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
               try
               {
                   UserProfileChangeCollection collection = profileConfigManager.GetChanges(query);
                   foreach (UserProfileChange change in collection)
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine(change.AccountName);                               
                       if (change is UserProfileSingleValueChange)
                       {
                           UserProfileSingleValueChange propertyChange = (UserProfileSingleValueChange)change;
                           Console.WriteLine(propertyChange.ProfileProperty.Name);
                       }
                   }
               }
               catch (UserNotFoundException)
               {
               }
```

[Read more on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilechangecollection.aspx) and [Example](http://msftplayground.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=6)

Answer (score 3):

Not really - the User Profile properties aren't stored in a list (which is where Event Receivers are registered) - they're all stored in the User Profile Database which is managed by the User Profile Service Application.

If you want to sync profile changes with an external system, you can write a [Timer Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798313.aspx) to look up the user profile properties and synchronise them with your external system. You would configure the timer job to run at an interval, and maybe use the [User Profile Change Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms549249%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to find out what's been changed.

Comment: +1 for timer job sync with external system.

Comment: @James Love: Thanks for your answer. I credited Falak Mahmood because he was providing more details. However, if I could have split the points, I would have.