# SharePoint MySite last modified date - Create CV based on mysite's properties / lists

Tags: 2013, user-profile, user, user-profile-property, mysite

What's the best way to find out when a property / custom property are changed on a mysite? Can't find any last modified on user properties.

We're trying to create CV based on users mysite. We've created custom lists / properties and we're thinking of using OpenXML to create the CV. We only have to find out how to detect if a user property are changed so it can create the CV.

I know there's a property called "last keyword added" or something that have a date stamp. But it seems that it's not detecting all the fields.

If I think a different way.. is there a way to deteckt "save" button when editing all user properties? That could actually work.

Maby this could work..

[Attach an event receiver to profile property update](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40970/attach-an-event-receiver-to-profile-property-update)

or

http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint-2010/monitor-sharepoint-user-profile-changes

The best I think would be to attach some code on the "save"-event, because if a user do any changes at all the cv have to be generated again.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a query against the change log. The "Event Receiver" really isn't it's just a timer job using the same approach detailed in the article. You could even run it all external to SharePoint from PowerShell if you wanted. No need to deploy custom code to SharePoint.